# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] while using external js file

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, xampp

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] this is the error I'm getting only when I'm using an external js file for my code otherwise if I just copy the angular code in the html/php file it just works.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Learn</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl" >

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"]);


    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

    });


})();
```

Error :

```
angular.min.js:sourcemap:7 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.6%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngRoute%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.6.6%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngRoute%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fang%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A76%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fang%252Fangular.min.js%253A26%253A408%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fang%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A439)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fang%252Fangular.min.js%253A26%253A182%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fang%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A290%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520p%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fang%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fang%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A138)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fang%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A322%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520p%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fang%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fang%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fang%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A76%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fang%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A70%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fang%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fang%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fang%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A322%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fang%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fang%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20hb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fang%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A250)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fang%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Uc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fang%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A332)
    at angular.min.js:sourcemap:7
    at angular.min.js:sourcemap:43
    at p (angular.min.js:sourcemap:8)
    at g (angular.min.js:sourcemap:42)
    at hb (angular.min.js:sourcemap:46)
    at c (angular.min.js:sourcemap:22)
    at Uc (angular.min.js:sourcemap:22)
    at we (angular.min.js:sourcemap:21)
    at angular.min.js:sourcemap:334
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:sourcemap:38)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular Routing("ngRoute") as dependency Injection you have to add routing script below angular in your html file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
```

or else remove dependency array.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add script for "ng-route".and is better to move script tag end of body tag .

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
      beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-
      PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" 
       crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


        <title>Learn</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl" >

        </div>

        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
       <script 
       src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-
       route.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

and no need to fonction({}) in app.js

var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"]);

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

});
```

Comment: please add explanation what you have changed / added to improve your answer

Comment: I change my answer and explain in my answer